# include в C++ для MemoryStatus

Tags: c++

Как понять какой #include нужно написать для MemoryStatus. Потому что MemoryStatus выделяется в коде красным и говорит что идентификатор не определен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гуглю, что такое MemoryStatus, первая ссылка https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_memorystatus
В пункте Requirements(Требования)-> в подпункте Header видим необходимый инклюд `winbase.h (include Windows.h)`